# Additional "Views" in android developers kit

Tags: android

Ive been working with the android development kit in eclipse and building a few programs. I use the xml layouts and the graphical layout to build the xml layout files. Under the "palette" there are numerous "views" such as the "analogclock", "button", "checkbox" and so on. I was wondering if there is any way to add additional "views" because the list that android provides isn't very long. Are there any types of addons that add views?, or just ways to add additional views to the graphical layout?
I hope i made this clear but if you need any clarifying let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few views. You can browse through them in the [View documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), looking under "Indirect Subclasses". There seem to be around 50 of them. Is this less than you're seeing?

There are also third-party libraries like [Droid-Fu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu) which supply additional components, including views.

Comment: Nice... which additional components does Droid-Fu supply?

Comment: I counted I only have 31 views, and i looked through the documentation and there are about 50. Is it possible I'm missing about 20? Oh and thanks for the link to droid-fu its helpful.

Comment: @Cristian, I see a WebImageView in their widgets directory, which seems very useful.